# A question regarding mass and energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy

Suppose that we a have a cube with mass $M$ and velocity $V$ directed towards $+x$. Than we apply a force in the direction $-x$ with a magnitude of $F$ for a distance $d$. We would find the final energy as $(1/2)MV^2-Fd$. The problem is that we always say that the velocity of the cube has decreased. But why does not the mass of an object change when its kinetical energy decreases.

What the previous paragraph intends to mean is that why do we always say that the velocity of an object decreases when its kinetic energy decreases rather than saying it mass decreases.

Comment: Is the velocity V the speed of light,  or anywhere near it, like 0.9999999c? Then we can talk about relativistic phenomena, otherwise not. You have put tag classical mechanics and asking questions about relativity??

Comment: We can assume that.

Comment: Then change the tag.

Comment: And write that.

Comment: What is a "force for a distance"?

Comment: @peterh applying a force F for a distance d. I do not get what is unclear.

Comment: I do not get where you missed the elemental Newtonian mechanics, but somewhere you got lost. Your question will be closed as unclear, because it is unclear.

Comment: @peterh go read.

Comment: Comment to the post (v6): You assume that the speed is comparable to the speed of light and use a non-relativistic formula $(1/2)MV^2$ for energy?

Comment: @Qmechanic no relativity involved.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of my special relativity lectures, *the mass of the object does change when its momentum changes*. Note, the rest mass of the object stays constant. But as the momentum of the body increases, the body will act as if it had greater mass. Intuitively, a grain of sand at $0.9c$ and $0.99c$ will have vastly different characteristics in terms of momentum, that would make the $0.99c$ grain of sand seem heavier.

The energy–momentum relation is:

$E^2 - (pc)^2 = (m_0 c^2)^2$

I think you are mixing up kinetic energy an momentum in this case. So as an objects momentum increases, also it's energy increases.

My answer might be oversimplified for this case, please let me know if I missed the mark.

Comment: "From my understanding of my general relativity lectures, the mass of the object does change when it's momentum is changed." In this case momentum also changes. So according to you in this example mass should also change. But we do not say so. That is what interests me. Why dont we also say that the mass changes in my example.

Comment: Oh sorry! I worded that wrong! The rest mass energy stays the same, it's constant. The rest mass is constant. But the energy of the system changes as the momentum changes. You could say the "equivalent" mass then changes, but that's wrong on a few different levels

Comment: @JamesBlackwell "my answer might be oversimplified for this case, please let me know if I missed the mark" - you have not attended any mark. The tag is classical mechanics and question is on relativity.  You should have flagged instead of answering. Mass change occurs at speeds near that of light, like 0.999999c.

Comment: I was just starting down that route in an edit on my post. I think I would be better off removing it. My apologies.

Comment: @JamesBlackwell avoid answering unclear questions.

Comment: @WrichikBasu Thats a fair point

Comment: It seems you know latex. The trick is here to enclose it between \$ signs, and an automatical javascript tool will convert it a latex formula. It will be nearly so good as with the original.

Comment: You still have not answered the question with your edits. @JamesBlackwell

Comment: @user9876217849124 The formula is not just $ e = mc^2 $ the rest mass energy is constant which is what most people would call the mass of the object. The relativistic mass will change as the momentum changes. So in your case the relativistic mass has decreased (but is still greater than the rest mass). Does that help?

Comment: @WrichikBasu , Relativity is a classical theory only.